# Performances of 'lineTo' method when going beyond canvas dimensions

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, html5-canvas

Using a canvas context, assuming I call `beginPath` then twice `lineTo` with `x=-999, y=-999` and  `x=50, y=50` then finally `stroke`, it will draw a line from the top-left corner to the (50,50) point.

During the process did the *top-left outside part* of the line was **draw from the outside** or did it was **draw from the visible canvas** part, in our case (0,0).

- In the first case, is it worth **safing the coordinates** with a `safeCoordinates` function, particurlarly if we need a lot of points, when we want to draw a mathematical function for example.
- In the second case well ok it's perfect.

See the above example where I have two red line without safing the coordinates and two green line with safe coordinates :

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Draw a line between two points
const drawLine = (color, fromX, fromY, toX, toY) => {
  context.beginPath();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.lineTo(fromX, fromY);
  context.lineTo(toX, toY);
  context.strokeStyle = color;
  context.stroke();
}

// Without coordinates safing
drawLine('#F00', -999, -999, 50, 50);
drawLine('#F00', 150, 150, 999 + canvas.width, 999 + canvas.height);

const safeCoordinateX = value => 
  value < 0 ? 0 : value > canvas.width ? canvas.width : value;

const safeCoordinateY = value => 
  value < 0 ? 0 : value > canvas.height ? canvas.height : value;

const safeCoordinates = (fromX, fromY, toX, toY) => 
  [safeCoordinateX(fromX), safeCoordinateY(fromY), safeCoordinateX(toX), safeCoordinateY(toY)];

// With coordinates safing
drawLine('#0F0', ...safeCoordinates(150, 50, 999 +  canvas.width, -999));
drawLine('#0F0', ...safeCoordinates(50, 150, -999, 999 + canvas.height));
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}
```

```html
<canvas width=200 height=200 />
```

Comment: What could make the perfs vary is the number of "verbs" that compose the path. If you think you can avoid adding new commands to the path because they would anyway be out of sight, then you may win something, but I guess it would need to be in the order of thousands of verbs avoided before it brings any improvement.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind, especially for function drawing thank's a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question we need a benchmark. Look at the following, the safe draw is taking longer than the unsafe draw. Probably due to extra calculation on your part.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Draw a line between two points
const drawLine = (color, fromX, fromY, toX, toY) => {
  context.beginPath();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.lineTo(fromX, fromY);
  context.lineTo(toX, toY);
  context.strokeStyle = color;
  context.stroke();
}

const safeCoordinateX = value => 
  value < 0 ? 0 : value > canvas.width ? canvas.width : value;

const safeCoordinateY = value => 
  value < 0 ? 0 : value > canvas.height ? canvas.height : value;

const safeCoordinates = (fromX, fromY, toX, toY) => 
  [safeCoordinateX(fromX), safeCoordinateY(fromY), safeCoordinateX(toX), safeCoordinateY(toY)];
 
   function drawSafe() {
  const t = Date.now();
  
  drawLine('#0F0', ...safeCoordinates(150, 50, 999 +  canvas.width, -999));
  drawLine('#0F0', ...safeCoordinates(50, 150, -999, 999 + canvas.height));
  
  return Date.now() - t;
}

function drawUnsafe() {
  const t = Date.now();
  
  drawLine('#F00', -999, -999, 50, 50);
  drawLine('#F00', 150, 150, 999 + canvas.width, 999 + canvas.height);
  
  return Date.now() - t;
}

function launchAndCalcTotTime(f) {
  let t = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i += 1) {
    t += f();
  }
  
  return t;
}

console.log(`Safe draw took ${launchAndCalcTotTime(drawSafe)}ms`);
console.log(`Unsafe draw took ${launchAndCalcTotTime(drawUnsafe)}ms`);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}
```

```html
<canvas width=200 height=200 />
```

---

To be sure about that you can also try to draw an extra big line and see if it changes the result. If the line is drawed, then it should slow down the execution. But answers is no.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Draw a line between two points
const drawLine = (color, fromX, fromY, toX, toY) => {
  context.beginPath();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.lineTo(fromX, fromY);
  context.lineTo(toX, toY);
  context.strokeStyle = color;
  context.stroke();
}

const safeCoordinateX = value => 
  value < 0 ? 0 : value > canvas.width ? canvas.width : value;

const safeCoordinateY = value => 
  value < 0 ? 0 : value > canvas.height ? canvas.height : value;

const safeCoordinates = (fromX, fromY, toX, toY) => 
  [safeCoordinateX(fromX), safeCoordinateY(fromY), safeCoordinateX(toX), safeCoordinateY(toY)];
 
   function drawSafe() {
  const t = Date.now();
  
  drawLine('#0F0', ...safeCoordinates(150, 50, 999 +  canvas.width, -999));
  drawLine('#0F0', ...safeCoordinates(50, 150, -999, 999 + canvas.height));
  
  return Date.now() - t;
}

function drawUnsafe() {
  const t = Date.now();
  
  drawLine('#F00', -999999999, -999999999, 5000000000, 500000000);
  drawLine('#F00', 0, 0, 9990000000 + canvas.width, 9990000000 + canvas.height);
  
  return Date.now() - t;
}

function launchAndCalcTotTime(f) {
  let t = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i += 1) {
    t += f();
  }
  
  return t;
}

console.log(`Safe draw took ${launchAndCalcTotTime(drawSafe)}ms`);
console.log(`Unsafe draw took ${launchAndCalcTotTime(drawUnsafe)}ms`);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}
```

```html
<canvas width=200 height=200 />
```

Comment: Thank's I'll do some benchmarks with function drawing then